# How to correctly interact with a view which is managed from another controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, view, controller

The question might seem too vague but I could not think of a better way to describe the idea, so I'll try to explain it in details.

I have MasterController attached to `<html>` tag of my SPA application. This MasterController contains all the logic and models for controlling the following UI elements:

- page title (`<title>` tag)
- subheader which displays the title of current page (like Customers, Orders, Settings etc.)
- name of the currently logged-in user
- some commonly used action buttons which will be used for all pages in the system. To be specific, these buttons are `Show filters`, `Export data to Excel` and `Add new record`.

While the first two items on this list can be managed through detection of current ui-router state (through its `$stateChangeSuccess` event), the last two (username and buttons) are somewhat problematic, especially the buttons.

I can manage the button actions using `$broadcast`, so every controller can be notified about clicks on any button. But the tricky part here is that the buttons might be needed in different combinations - one page might need all of them, and another one might need none.

Let's say, ui-router loads some CustomersController. At that point MasterController receives `$stateChangeSuccess` event and by default hides all the buttons.

**But now, how does CustomersController tell to MasterController that CustomersController will need two specific buttons from the very beginning?**

Theoretically, I could use `$emit` from CustomersController to send an event to MasterController, but it somehow feels ugly. Events are meant for, well, events and not for sending requests like "hey, MasterController, if you are somewhere up the scope, can you please show the following buttons?".

Of course, I might be wrong and maybe there is some way to use Angular event system to manage this scenario in clean way.

What came to my mind is that maybe in the `$stateChangeSuccess` event I could somehow detect if there are currently any listeners for my button click events and then I could hide buttons which do not have any listeners attached, but I'm not sure how to do it, and I'm not sure whether it will work as expected - whether old listeners will be detached when ui-router recreates the view with another controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just nesting controllers, their corresponding scopes actually make use of **prototypical inheritance**. So you could just define a function `$scope.configureButtons` in your MasterController and call this function from the `$scope` in your nested CustomerController.

If Controllers are not nested you would probably need to resort to `$rootScope.$broadcast` for setting up your buttons.

Comment: It gets tricky because I'm using `controller as` syntax. I have seen some workarounds for such cases here on SO, but they all seem to mess up the OOP idea extending CustomerController or its $scope from MasterController. Such inheritance It is like saying that CustomerController is a special case of MasterController, which is a lie because their relation is "container -> contained" and not "general implementation -> more specific implementation". But I guess I'll have to sacrifice OOP ideals for functionality :)

Comment: In my opinion, conservative OOP paradigmas aren't applicable to angular at all and will stand in your way when dealing with it. Angular has its own ways of dealing with DRY principles, namely encapsulating UX functionality into directives and data functionality into services. Controllers are just the glue inbetween and if you want to get the most out of angular, you need to be very disciplined and use the controller exclusively as your view-model. Again, just in my experience, if you try to obey by this principles, you will find yourself standing in your own way much less frequently. :)

Comment: I said in my experience, because when I first entered angular, I had a lot of struggles determining best practices and in my first project, consisting of only one view, ended up comfortably doing almost everything in a single controller, which was fine for me, until I needed to extend that project and add two other views. It became real painful as I was disobeying DRY a lot, forgot to copy paste updates on repeated code, etc. I then took the time and structured the app and ever since I have become acustomed to this style and am very happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply using diferent controllers for each view? Maybe generalize a bit the CustomerController and extend it (specialize it) for every combination of buttons you need. Using the $stateChangeSuccess feels like avoiding polymorphism to me.

Comment: Extending controllers from some base is a good idea, but there is just one problem - views cannot be inherited. I'll have to duplicate the HTML code of buttons (or use some duplicate template importing mechanism) for each view which is managed by ui-router. But maybe there is some way to tell ui-router to leave existing parts intact and bind to scope when it is attaching a newly created controller to HTML element? Then I could add the button template once and reload controller-specific view parts only. Still, seems tricky, therefore I left the buttons in the header for now.

Answer (score 0):

Today I got a tricky idea based on @Diego Castaño Chillarón 's answer. I thought - but is it possible to use ui-router to swap controller of existing view and will it rebind also the $scope? And will I still be able to replace inner parts of the loaded view?

It turned out that it is doable! Now I don't have to control the common view fragments from the master control, and I don't need also to inherit or duplicate them - I just switch the controller to the required one through ui-router.

Like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("customers", {
            url: "^/customers",
            views: {
                "controller": {
                    controller: "CustomerController as cntrlr"
                },                                    
                "page@customers": // <- this is important, absolute name required for ui-router to find nested view
                {
                    templateUrl: "customers"
                }
            }
        }) // other routes follow in the same manner
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="routes-root" ui-view="controller">

  <div id="content-header-buttons">
      <button type="button" ng-click="master.toggleFilter()">Filter data</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="cntrlr.exportClicked()">Export</button>
      <button type="button" ng-click="cntrlr.createNewClicked()">Create</button>
   </div>
    <div id="view-content" ui-view="page"></div>
</div>
```

As you see, I left master controller to control only visibility for filters block, which won't change.

But controller itself is attached to `#routes-root` element, preserving inner content, and ui-router (or Angular) is smart enough to attach $scope and `cntrlr` variable to the loaded controller. And then I load inner view into `#view-content`, which also gets attached to the already loaded controller.